# How to set the default acronyms style to my own glossary?

Tags: glossaries

I have a document with two glossaries. One for the acronyms and one for the symbols. I like the default style of the acronyms glossary and I want the same for the symbols. I have tried all the possible *styles*, and non looks like it.

What should I do? thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,toc]{glossaries} 
...
\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of main Symbols}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gnss}{type=\acronymtype,
 name={GNSS},
 description={Global Navigation Satellite System},
 nonumberlist=true}
...
\newglossaryentry{Fs}{type=symbols,name=  
 {\ensuremath{Fs}},
 sort=Fs,
 description={sampling frequency},
 nonumberlist=true}
...
\begin{document}
...
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=symbols,style={long}]
%\printglossary[type=symbols,style={super}]
%\printglossary[type=symbols,style={list}]
%\printglossary[type=symbols,style={listdotted}]
%\printglossary[type=symbols,style={listgroup}]
%\printglossary[type=symbols,style={altlist}]
%\printglossary[type=symbols,style={tree}]
%\printglossary[type=symbols,style={index}]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly change the style in the optional argument of `\printglossary`, all glossaries will use whatever happens to be the currently style. The default style is `list`, so in the following both glossaries use the `list` style:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,toc]{glossaries} 

\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of main Symbols}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gnss}{type=\acronymtype,
 name={GNSS},
 description={Global Navigation Satellite System},
 nonumberlist=true}

\newglossaryentry{Fs}{type=symbols,name=  
 {\ensuremath{Fs}},
 sort=Fs,
 description={sampling frequency},
 nonumberlist=true}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=symbols]

\chapter{Sample}
\gls{gnss} and \gls{Fs}.

\end{document}
```

The first glossary (`\acronymtype`) looks like:

[image: Image of first glossary]

The second glossary (`symbols`) looks like:

[image: Image of second glossary]

The reason for the apparent difference is that in the first case the `name` is in text-mode, so it picks up the surrounding bold font, and in the second case the `name` is in math-mode, so it doesn't pick up the surrounding bold font.

Essentially, this is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[GNSS] Global Navigation Satellite System
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item[$Fs$] sampling frequency
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

which looks like:

[image: image of lists]